# Common Table Expression in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I am just learning the CTE and I want to create the dynamic query inside the WITH clause.

Below is what i have written code.

```
WITH name1 AS (
    SELECT schema_name as my_schema
    FROM public.schema_table
), name2 AS (
    SELECT num_rows as my_row
    FROM my_schema.row_table
)
SELECT my_row
from name2;
```

From the first query inside the WITH give number of schema exist in one database and that schema name return by

```
SELECT schema_name as my_schema 
FROM public.schema_table
```

I want to use in second query as I am saving it to my_schema.

but when i run this query then it gives me error like my_schema not exists that correct because I want to use the value my_schema contains.

How can you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you do not appear to have used `name1` anywhere in your query, so I suspect you may not have understood `WITH` fully.

However it looks like you might have multiple tables called `row_table` each living in it's own schema and want to create a query that will let you choose which schema to fetch from.

```
FROM my_schema.row_table
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

`my_schema` is not a *variable*, it is the *name* of the schema. To do what you want you are going to have to use the pg_catalog tables to find the `oid` for the relation within the schema that you need and look up the information that way.

An alternative solution could be to manipulate the search path to do your bidding:

```
BEGIN;
    SET LOCAL SCHEMA 'my_schema';
    SELECT num_rows FROM row_table;   -- will use my_schema.
COMMIT;
```

Comment: ok. got it. I will check... but as we can do this in plpgsql function with EXECUTE 'SELECT num_rows as my_row FROM || quote_literal(my_schema) || '.' || row_table; Can we do like that in CTE i mean in WITH clause ?

Comment: Actuall just want to correct you. I want to use value in my_schema. Actually my_schema is not the schema name but value stored in my_schema that we have to use. So i think SET LOCAL SCHEMA my_schema also will fail. because we have to use values inside that like quote_literal(my_schema). Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter it's an [alias](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set.html) for set search_path... appeared in 8.4+